# Detecting purchasing patterns

Tags: machine-learning, sequential-pattern-mining

I work for an e-commerce whose users take a quiz with some questions that we use to segment them.

Which algorithm/approach could we use to get insight like this?

`People that answered A and B but not C purchased 15% more than the average`

`People that answered B and D purchased mostly products X and Y`

Comment: You could try decision trees

Comment: Thanks but with more than 50 questions, overfitting would be a big issue here. I was looking for something like FP-Growth algorithm.

Comment: you can regularise a tree just as with any other machine learning algorithm. eg by tree depth see eg https://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html